# Is this a tautology: $\forall xP(x) \implies Q(x)$ if there's no $x$ such that $P(x)$?

Tags: logic

Is this a tautology: $\forall xP(x) \implies Q(x)$ if there's no $x$ such that $P(x)$?

I know that if there was an exists there instead of a for all, the antecedent would be false and thus the implication true. But this one confuses me.

Could someone clarify this form me?

E: This question comes from an exercise I have which says: Let $\Gamma$ be an unsatisfiable set of formulas. Let $\alpha$ be a formula. Does $\alpha\in C(\Gamma) $, where $C(X)$ denotes the consequences of $X$?

The definition of consequence I have says $\alpha\in C(X)$ if $\forall v$ valuation$:v(\Gamma)=\{1\} \implies v(\alpha)=1$. As my $\Gamma$ has no valuations that satisfy it, this should be true, right?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking whether $\neg \exists xP(x)\to \forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))$ is a tautology, the answer is yes.

Comment: Are you possibly mixing predicate calculus with propositional calculus?

Comment: Hmm, I may be. I had this doubt for this particular exercise, but I wanted to know if this was true for a more general case. Did I extrapolate that incorrectly?

Comment: *Tautology* - in the context of mathematical logic - does not mean "vacuously true".

Comment: I don't understand that part, why if some formula is vacuously true isn't it a tautology?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I think you did extrapolate incorrectly. How do you define valuations for predicate formulas?

Comment: In **all** math log textbooks (see e.g. Enderton, page 23) a formula $\varphi$ of propositional logic is defiend as a *tautology* (written $\vDash \varphi$) when "**every** truth assignment (for the sentence symbols in $\varphi$ ) satisfies it." If we "extrapolate" this def to a f-o formula, we say that $\varphi$ is *valid* when **every** interpretation satisfy it... and this is not the your case.

Comment: The following formula of f-o set theory : $x \in \emptyset \to x \ne x$ is *vacuously true* (for no $x : x \in \emptyset$) but it is **not** a tautology (i.e. true in every interpretation).

Answer (score 3):

The formula is a *predicate* (or *first-order*) one: in this context, we have two uses of the term *tautology* :

*(i)* a f-o formula is called a *tautology* when it is an "instance" of a propositional tautology. The formula $∀xP(x) \to Q(x)$ is an instance of the propositional formula $p \to q$, which is **not** a tautology.

*(ii)* a f-o formula is (sometimes) called a *tautology* when it is *valid* (i.e. *true* in every interpretation). The formula $∀xP(x) \to Q(x)$ is - as you say - *true* in every interpretation where there are no $P$'s, but of course is not *valid*.

To verify this, we can interpret the formula in $\mathbb N$ and interpret $Q$ with $x < 0$ and $P$ with $x \ge 0$ : clearly $\forall x (x \ge 0) \to (x < 0)$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$.

---

Thus, in both cases, it is not correct to say that the formula is a *tautology*.

In all mathematical logic textbooks (see e.g. Enderton, page 23) a formula $\varphi$ of *propositional logic* is defiend as a *tautology* (written $\vDash \varphi$) when:

> every truth assignment (for the sentence symbols in $\varphi$) satisfies it.

If we "extrapolate" this definition to the first-order language, we get the definition of *valid* formula:

> we say that $\varphi$ is valid when every interpretation satisfy it,

and this is not the case of the formula above.

What we have is : $¬∃P(x) \vDash ∀xP(x) \to Q(x)$, that reads :

> $¬∃P(x)$ *logically* (and not : *tautologically*) *implies* $∀xP(x) \to Q(x)$.

---

Regarding the added part, the answer is : YES.

If no truth assignment satisfies every member of $\Gamma$, then for any $\varphi$, it is vacuously true that $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a tautology: $\forall x[P(x) \implies Q(x)]$ if there's no $x$ such that $P(x)$?  (Inserted presumed brackets.)

Yes.

Disclaimer: This proof probably won't be using exactly the axioms you are allowed, but it should be possible to translate it into your own system.

1. We have $\forall x: \neg P(x)$
2. Suppose $P(y)$.
3. From 1, we have $\neg P(y)$.
4. From 3, we have $\neg\neg P(y)\implies Q(y)$ since anything follows
   from a falsehood.
5. From 4, $P(y)\implies Q(y)$, removing the $\neg\neg$.
6. From 2 and 5, $Q(y)$ by detachment
7. From 2 and 6, $P(y)\implies Q(y)$, the conclusion.
8. Generalizing, $\forall x :[P(x)\implies Q(x)] $

Comment: Also, I think "since anything follows from a falsehood" is the most important sentence here.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Corrected bracketing. Thanks.